# Core data create not persisting entity object

Tags: ios, core-data

Is it possible to create `NSManagedObject` object which will be not saved in db. Or maybe I could create and delete it, then will I have access to all properties?

I am downloading and saving my own items, and I need to download and display other user items which I don't have to save, so that's why my question. Of course I can add some property with 'userid' or some other but simpler would be don't save this items just use them to display...

Comment: If you don't call save on the context, your entity won't be saved. What are you trying to do and what have you tried? Your question is vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create managed objects that aren't associated with a context by passing `nil` for the context argument when creating one. For example

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Foo" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *tempObject = [[NSManagedObject alloc] initWithEntity:entityDescription insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
```

If you later want to insert the object, use the `insertObject:` on `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Comment: What if I need relationship to other object in context? Now it throws:
reason: 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'category' between objects in different contexts

Comment: Then you have to insert the object into the context, because that's one of the restrictions of how Core Data works. You can delete it later if you want.